# in the given code will the compiler insert super(); statement in both the animal constructors?

Tags: java

```
public class Animal {
    String name;

    Animal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    Animal() {
        this(makeRandomName());
    }

    static String makeRandomName() {
        int x = (int) (Math.random() * 5);
        String name = new String[] {"Fluffy", "Fido","Rover", "Spike","Gigi"}[x];
        return name;
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Animal a = new Animal();
        System.out.println(a.name);
        Animal b = new Animal("Zeus");
        System.out.println(b.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: ignore 6 in the 5th line

Comment: Why are people so much interested in `Animal`s? I guess I saw 3 questions in the past 44 minutes, which use this name for their experiments.

Comment: Can you please edit the question. Make the code well indented using the code braces first.  `Code Start

Code End`

As above.

Comment: Could be a homework assignment @Hackerdarshi :)

Comment: No. It will not. Just into the constructor that does not a) call another constructor using `this` or b) call `super`.

Comment: @Satya Yeah. Maybe

Answer (score 3):

No, for the `Animal()` constructor that calls the other constructor (using `this(makeRandomName());`), `super()` won't be added. It would be added only to the `Animal(String name)` constructor.

This means, of course, that both constructors will end up executing the super class's constructor (i.e. `Object`'s constructor).

Answer (score 2):

A `super()` call will be inserted unless there is a `super()` or `this()` call already explicitly present.